# What's the word Avraham used for his religion?

Tags: words, hashkafah-philosophy, tanach, avot-patriarch-fathers

What was the biblical name of the religion or faith Avraham belonged to? the word he used to distinguish his faith from other, pagan belief systems?

Comment: that edit is perfectly fine and does not at all change the meaning of the question thanks @msh210 for helping out

Comment: but the background should have been given

Comment: Ali, the background you gave concerned whether _Avraham_ is halachically considered to have been Jewish, which has nothing whatever to do with what he called his faith. That's why I thought (and think) removing it would improve the question. I'll be glad to reopen it if it's a clear question even if it includes irrelevancies, but don't expect to get answers that address your actual question (or upvotes) in the latter case.

Comment: I don't think there's such a thing in the Bible as a noun for any belief system. My gut tells me that that level of abstraction in language may not have existed yet at all in Biblical times.

Comment: I'm guessing he'd call it _monotheism_.

Comment: @DoubleAA I wouldn't have thought he spoke English, but if you can argue (or have evidence) for that answer, then I suggest you post it as an answer.

Comment: we don't know what word he used because he didn't write down the torah. The text in Gen 14:13 refers to him as an Ivri a few verses before he makes an impassioned statement regarding his belief in god.

Comment: I wouldn't think he had a name for his faith, but others called G-d "the G-d of Abraham".

Comment: Also, HaShem told Moshe to call Him ["G-d of the Hebrews"](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0203.htm#18) when speaking to Pharaoh.

Answer (score 4):

There’s no indication that Avraham’s belief system had a name. In fact, there is no word used in Tanach for any belief system so far as I know. (Or, for that matter, for the concepts of “belief system” or “philosophy” or “religion”.) Tanach mentions the worship of this pagan god or that pagan pantheon, and contrasts them with the worship of the One God of Israel.

From Jewish tradition associated with Avraham’s hospitality, we can guess at the core of what he himself taught: there is one God, God the All-Sufficing (*El Shaddai*), to Whom we owe gratitude for everything we have.

Avraham also knew of God’s Justice (*cf.* [*Bereishis* 18:25](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0118.htm#25)), and taught that God demands righteousness/charity and justice from His followers ([*ibid.* 19](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0118.htm#19)).

But I repeat, there is no word associated with this philosophy or religion found in Tanach.

Comment: @J._C._Salomon Well, the TaNaKH (Psalm 14,1 אָמַר נָבָל בְּלִבּוֹ,    אֵין אֱלֹהִים) does label those who do NOT believe in God as a FOOL. So, in some sense, their belief system had a name: FOOLISHNESS.