# Were Rivka, Rachel, and Leah monotheists prior to marrying their respective husbands?

Tags: historical-figures, genesis-bereishith

I was wondering what the religious affiliation of Rivkah, Rachel, and Leah were prior to getting married. Did they all already acknowledge HaShem as G-d or at least subscribed to monotheism?

Comment: Rashi (on the verse that mentions that Rivkah was a virgin at the time that she met Eliezer) points out that Rivkah maintained her virginity in all ways - unlike the other maidens of the land, and the Midrash says that she was compared to a rose amongst the thorns

Comment: @User123 so is it safe to assume she was a bat Noach?

Comment: @ddas91600, I guess so - I don’t see why not…

Comment: @Harel13 oops my bad, somehow read Sarah :)

Comment: Related: "[What's the word Avraham used for his religion?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26734/1368)"

Comment: By "prior to getting married", do you mean 'in the days leading up to marrying'? Or, do you mean 'before they even were aware of the possibility of marrying [their respective to-be-husbands]'? If the former, it's conceivable that Rachel and Leah became acquainted with, and accepted HaShem as G-d, in the 7 years Ya'akov worked for the first he married. It could even be argued (less convincingly) the same for Rivkah, between when she met Eliezer and when she saw Yitzchak. If the latter, as Lavan was an idolator, where would they learn/know anything other than idolatry?

Comment: Rivkah was probably at least somewhat aware of Avraham's religion given that Lavan, according to Chazal, knew to clear out idols from the house when Eliezer came.

Comment: Just as Abraham, using his search for truth, discovered G'd in a house of idol worship, Rivka, Rachel & Leah, being as truthful, might well have come to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 8):

Our Sages [(Bereishis Rabbah 70:16)](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereshit_Rabbah.70.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) tell us that "Leah's eyes were weak" from crying "whilst praying" that she wouldn't have to marry Eisav. In fact, they say that her prayers were so powerful, that it brought about that she married Yaakov first. This was before Yaakov came on the scene, so it seems she already then recognized G'd as The One to pray to.

Answer (score -4):

My first reaction was The question is somewhat n/a because
Rbka is the Shekhinah.
Rachel is Prayer.
Leah is the Torah.
As is known in the (Sefarim) [meaning Zohar etc ].

However it's also a klal the vessel only becomes what it is because of what fills it and makes it a vessel. Therefore

- Yishak makes or is the reason or ensures the Shekhinah (Rbka) is monotheist.
- Yisrael and Jacob ensure Rachel and Leah are etc.

The best way to accomplish all this in devotions is to say the prayer, Na Nach Nachma Nachman which is also Torah (Saba said the Petek is a Sefer) and wholesome like the Lord Yishak.

Whether they are active or passive (let's say that's how we read "monotheist") depends if they are in Mochin d'katnut (immature) or Mochin d'gadlut (Matrix). You can read all about that in the kitvei Ari the anatomist of the Soul. And Sarah is the Matrinonita the Blessed Mother.